# Vscode autofilling for get and set information

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, comments, autofill

When using vscode, it helps me when writing get and set methods  and auto fills it in this format:

```
     /**
     * @param strength the strength to set
     */
     public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }
```

However if I were writing this  I would do this:

```
    /**
     * sets the strength variable
     */
    public void setStrength(int newStrength) {
        newStrength = strength;
    }
```

Which would be more correct? Also what does the comment mean in the first one?

Comment: Second snippet has a bug, because it's assigning to parameter variable, not to instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a convention for parameter names in getters and setters. So technically they are both correct. Although, I have always used your first example even when I don't auto generate my methods and you will find a majority of open source Java code will use your first example.

Your comment is a [javadoc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html). Build tools like Maven and Gradle offer the [ability of compiling API documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html). IDE's (like VSCode) will also parse the javadoc and provide that to you dynamically. You can see this in action when you hover over method / class names.

I would become familiar with Java documentation, especially if someone else will look at your code. [There are quite a few Java tags](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm).